# Separate header with Enum Class and operator overload

Tags: c++, class, enums, linker, namespaces

I am completing a drill in *Programming Principles and Practice using C++ 2e* on p.338

I have:

- A class interface -> d0.h
- A class implementation -> d0.cpp
- A header with a class enum deceleration and operator overload
- The main cpp file -> d0m.cpp

I receive the following error upon trying to compile:
    `g++ d0.cpp d0m.cpp -o d0.o -std=gnu++11`

```
/tmp/name/cc09EWiA.o: In function `chrono::operator<<(std::ostream&, chrono::Month const&)':
d0m.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `chrono::operator<<(std::ostream&, chrono::Month const&)'
/tmp/name/ccPAVaW9.o:d0.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems the issue is the operator overload in Month.h

This is how I understand the includes to flow:

```
month.h
^
|
|          
d0.h<---------d0m.cpp       
^
|
|
d0.cpp
```

It is my understanding that it is good practice to place enums and (enum class?) in their own header. By extension, it seemed logical to include the operator overload there as well.

Is the right way to do this to define the operator overload in Month.h and create the definition in Month.cpp?

```
// Month.h -> Enum Class used in Date71 class definition in d0.h 
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace chrono
{
    enum class Month
    {
        jan=1,feb,mar,apr,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec
    };

    const vector<string> month_tbl = {"January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "November",
                    "December"};

    extern ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Month& m)
    {
        return os << month_tbl[int(m)];
    }
}

#pragma once
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Month.h"

namespace chrono
{
    class Date71
    {
        public:
            Date71(int y, Month m, int d); // check for valid date and initialize
            void add_date(int n); // increase Date by n days
            Month month();
            int day();
            int year();
        private:
            int y; // year
            Month m;
            int d; // day
    };



// d0.cpp
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "d0.h"

namespace chrono
{
    Month Date71::month(){return m;}
    int Date71::day(){return d;}
    int Date71::year(){return y;}

    void Date71::add_date(int n)
    {
        d = (d < 31) ? d+n : d;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Date71& b)
    {
        return os <<'('<<b.year()
              <<','<<b.month()
              <<','<<b.day()<<')';
    }
}

//d0m.cpp
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "d0.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    chrono::Date71 forth(1978,chrono::Month::jul,25);
    chrono::Date71 forthC = forth;
    thirdC.add_date(1);
    chrono::Date71 forthW(1978,chrono::Month::jul,35);

    cout << forth;
    cout << forthC;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message does not match the shown code. The error message refers to "extern vector<string> month_tbl". The header file declares "const vector<string> month_tbl". Additionally, even if this were to compile, the subsequent link will fail due to duplicate symbols declares in multiple translation units, despite your best efforts to carpetbomb the header files with non-standard "pragmas". You are well advised to stop using compiler-specific, non-standard silliness like "#pragma once", and instead learn how scoping should work correctly in standard C++; then write portable code, instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `#pragma once` is a perfectly valid option, especially considering that all compilers worth using implement it correctly and the alternative "standard C++" version is so awful to handle manually that IDEs try to implement randomized header guards instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I have updated the error message. Thank you for pointing that out. Also, I acknowledge a lack of understanding regarding the linking and scoping process that results in this error. I am here to seek understanding that has eluded my googling effort. As for the '#pragma once' it certainly is not standard however, it is well supported and thus portable. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability)

Comment: ... and, right on queue, the link error that I anticipated. See my original comment for what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every function definition that may occur in multiple Translation Units must be at least one of:

- `inline` (this is implied if the definition is in the `class` body or if it has `constexpr`)
- `static` at global scope
- in an anonymous `namespace`
- a `template` (with some caveats involving `extern template`)

Comment: It is my understanding that this is true due to: `inline` -> no linkage due to replacing function call with the function. `static` -> When used in a namespace, including Global, meaning that the linkage is to be internal. Internal linkages are not visible to other translation units. anonymous `namespace` -> no linkage. Template -> _I haven't really gotten here yet_

Comment: The most useful references online about linkage I have found are: [http://www.goldsborough.me/c/c++/linker/2016/03/30/19-34-25-internal_and_external_linkage_in_c++/](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/c++/linker/2016/03/30/19-34-25-internal_and_external_linkage_in_c++/) and [https://gaubuali.wordpress.com/linkage-in-c-and-c/](https://gaubuali.wordpress.com/linkage-in-c-and-c/)

Comment: @Bwomchickabowow You're right about `static` (and anonymous `namespace` which is (basically) the same), but wrong about `inline` (and `template` which is (basically) the same). `inline` does not actually imply that the function will be inlined - it's just a hint - the important thing is that it changes the linkage of symbol (check with `nm`, e.g. from `T` to `W`). See also `extern template`, but note that GCC is far more forgiving than the standard in that case.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue I moved the operator overload from *Month.h* into a new file *Month.cpp*.

After this, I was getting some pretty weird errors about the compiler not recognizing types like `vector`. Investigating further revealed that  `../../std_lib_facilities.h` included  *d0.h* had already included many standard library components but also had `using namespace std` in there too.

With that being known, I replace any instances of std library headers with `../../std_lib_facilities.h` and everything then compiled.

Note: `std_lib_facilities.h` is the header from the book. It attempts to insulate the reader from some of the details of the libraries and their inclusion in general.